# Fixed and centered div with dimensions

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'd like to put a fixed div of 60% x 50% dimension into the center of screen. What values of A, B, C, D need to be used to achieve that effect?
    div {
      position: fixed;
      top: A%;
      left: B%;
      width: 60%;
      height: 50%;
      transform: translate(-C%, -D%)
    }

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6ykh0php/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for

```
.centered {
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```